# React Native Woocommerce Rest Api Fetch Error

Tags: react-native, woocommerce-rest-api

**I am using REACT NATİVE for a project. I need to integrate the website and the mobile application. I have to use WooCommerce Rest API for that. I'm trying to learn but I can't see the data I want to capture. I can not see anything.
**

```
import WooCommerceAPI from 'react-native-woocommerce-api';
const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'http://myurl', // Your store URL
  ssl: true,
  consumerKey: '****************', 
  consumerSecret: '***************', 
  wpAPI: true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
  version: 'v3', // WooCommerce WP REST API version
  queryStringAuth: true
});
```

**WooCommerce Config**

```
class X extends Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

componentWillMount() {
    // GET example
    return(
    WooCommerce.get('products') .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                products: [...prevState.products, ...responseJson],
                isLoading: false
            }));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        }))
}
```

---

```
<FlatList
                        data={this.state.products}
                        renderItem={({item}) => <View>
                            <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                            <Text>{WooCommerce.get('products').id}</Text>
                        </View>}
                        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
                    />
```

**Data is not fetching, i dont see anything, what is a problem ?**

Comment: Have you replaced `consumerKey` and `consumerSecret` with actual values instead of `***` placeholder? What is the error showing up on your console after api call?

Comment: Yes, I replaced it with real values. I'm not getting an error but can't see the data

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer might be coming late but for those who are having the same issue. You don't need to add the first then with response.json(). Please look at examples here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-woocommerce-api

```
componentWillMount() {
    // GET example
    return(
    WooCommerce.get('products')
        .then(responseJson => {
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                products: [...prevState.products, ...responseJson],
                isLoading: false
            }));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        }))
}
```